# android audio player

Tags: android, seek, audio-player

I want to develope audio player that has seek functionality.
Right now I am doing only play and stop functionality. How can I 
add seek to functionality to it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    setContentView(R.layout.playingactivity);
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mPath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.path);
    mPath.setText(GlobalVariable.getstrEmail());
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("/sdcard/download/test.mp3");   
    mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.show(0);    
    mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    mVideoView.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use: `mediaPlayer.seekTo(int msec)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"   >
<VideoView android:id="@+id/surface_view"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</VideoView></LinearLayout
```